# Outputting a Select Query in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm used to using `BindParam()` and since this is a `SELECT query` Param's are not related. Basically I'm trying to make a notification system that will check the database and if any of the rows' status is '0' then it would output all the rows information.

I have the following columns: `id, api, request, apikey, apiemail, keyauth, ip, dateandtime, status`.

How would I make PDO put all the information it gathers from all rows with `status='0'` and put them into usable variables like: `$id, $api, $request`? Of course there could be more then one row with `status='0'` so maybe have the variables arrays and output like `$id[0], $id[1]` e.t.c.

PDO:

```
<?php

include('/cdn/global/db.php');

$opt = array( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname";

$DBH = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $opt);
$DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT id, api, request, apikey, apiemail, keyauth, ip, dateandtime, status FROM apirequests WHERE status = 0");

$STH->execute();

echo "<p>The link is now in Queue, An admin will check the link soon!</p>";


# close the connection  
$DBH = null;

######

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fetch them as objects(Also order by a field if you want the results in a specific order):

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT id, api, request, apikey, apiemail, keyauth, ip, dateandtime, status FROM apirequests WHERE status = 0 ORDER BY id");
$STH->execute();
if($STH->rowCount()){
 while($row = $STH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
  #Perform whatever operation you need on a single row
  echo "$row->id, $row->api, $row->request, $row->apikey, $row->apiemail\n";
 }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, Much more minified version of the other answer's foreach loop.

Comment: I have questions, How would I do multiple queries so I can get the info from other databases the same way?

Comment: Put lines 1-3 in a function, replace the select with an argument to the function that will contain actual query. Instead of looping return $STH once you have checked for number of rows then the while loop will be where you invoked your function so you can operate on your data accordingly.

Comment: Then that would make my answer irrelavant to the main question, try this http://collabedit.com/wa4j8

Comment: Changed the answer to this one because it is a more minified way of doing this and he also helped me a ton on collabedit with much more then what was asked here.

Answer (score 0):

> put them into usable variables like: $id, $api, $request e.t.c

There is no point in doing that. `$row['id']` is no less usable but WAY more flexible. Although you can use `extract()` function to assign array members to corresponding variables.

> of course there could be more then one row with status='0' so maybe have the variables arrays and output like $id[0], $id[1] e.t.c

This would make even less sense and nobody is doing it this way. Anyways, PDO won't make such variables for you. Instead, array of rows have to be used, like shown in other answers.

Comment: So $row['id'] is the best way to go about it?

Answer (score -1):

```
$value = 0;     
$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT id, api, request, apikey, apiemail, keyauth, ip, dateandtime, status FROM apirequests WHERE status = ?");
$STH->execute(array($value));
 $variable[] = $STH->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: May you please describe whats going on in this answer?

Comment: set your variable into $STH->execute function as a array you can set multiple condition as well. When you get dynamically where condition variable put here into array.

Comment: Doesnt seem to work at all :/ [31-Aug-2015 13:34:38 America/New_York] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: stmt in /home/unfed/public_html/test.php on line 15
[31-Aug-2015 13:34:38 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetchAll() on null in /home/unfed/public_html/test.php on line 15

Comment: $STH->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); use this

Comment: That works and outputs as expected but like the other answer I need a way for it to be like $variable[id] or something so I can loop its output. So I can show each rows id in order and loop its output.

Comment: you can use while loop for this and customization is needed as per your requirement. you need to do modification in output